# iterative binary_search Python implementation

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel, binary-search

I did a Python implementation of binary search implementation
iteratively. It passes all of the test and I was wondering if I can
get any feedback.

```
#!python

def binary_search_iterative(array, item):
    """iteratively return the index of the item with binary search or None if not found"""
    # Sorted array that has to be the condition
    # go through several iteration until we found this
    # First, set the lower_index = 0
    # upper_index as the length of array -1
    lower_index = 0
    upper_index = len(array) - 1
    # iteration until it is found
    while lower_index <= upper_index:
        # calculate the middle index by sum the lower_index and upper_index and divide by 2
        middle_index = (lower_index + upper_index) // 2 # // is int division
        # check if the item is found
        if array[middle_index] == item:
            return middle_index
        elif array[middle_index] < item:
            lower_index = middle_index + 1
        elif array[middle_index] > item:
            upper_index = middle_index - 1

    # Did not find
    return None

def binary_search(array, item):
    """return the index of item in sorted array or None if item is not found"""
    # change this to call your implementation to verify it passes all tests
    return binary_search_iterative(array, item)
```

link to my linear search code:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/be81dc4ab1a26328785ed8cffce33346

```
def linear_search(array, item):
    for index, value in enumerate(array):
        if item == value:
            return index  # found
    return None  # not found
```

---

```
#!python

from search import linear_search, binary_search
import unittest


class SearchTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_binary_search_with_items_in_list(self):
        # binary search requires list values to be in sorted order
        names = ['Alex', 'James', 'Julia', 'Matthew', 'Nathan', 'Conrad', 'John']
        # binary search should return the index of each item in the list
        assert binary_search(names, 'Alex') == 0
        assert binary_search(names, 'James') == 1
        assert binary_search(names, 'Julia') == 2
        assert binary_search(names, 'Matthew') == 3
        assert binary_search(names, 'Nathan') == 4
        assert binary_search(names, 'Conrad') == 5
        assert binary_search(names, 'John') == 6

    def test_binary_search_with_items_in_list2(self):
        # binary search requires list values to be in sorted order
        names = ['Person0', 'Person1', 'Person2', 'Person3', 'Person4', 'Person5', 'Person6']
        # binary search should return the index of each item in the list
        assert linear_search(names, 'Person0') == 0
        assert linear_search(names, 'Person1') == 1
        assert linear_search(names, 'Person2') == 2
        assert linear_search(names, 'Person3') == 3
        assert linear_search(names, 'Person4') == 4
        assert linear_search(names, 'Person5') == 5
        assert linear_search(names, 'Person6') == 6

    def test_binary_search_with_items_not_in_list(self):
        # binary search requires list values to be in sorted order
        names = ['Alex', 'James', 'Julia', 'Matthew', 'Nathan', 'Conrad', 'John']
        # binary search should return None for any item not in the list
        assert binary_search(names, 'Jeffrey') is None
        assert binary_search(names, 'nobody') is None

    def test_binary_search_with_items_not_in_list2(self):
        # binary search requires list values to be in sorted order
        names = ['Person5', 'Person2', 'Person4', 'Person1', 'Person3', 'Person6', 'Person0']
        # binary search should return None for any item not in the list
        assert binary_search(names, 'Jack-in-Box') is None
        assert binary_search(names, 'nobody') is None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: just fixed the unit-testing by importing both binary_search and linear_search to unit-test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Be sure to check [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) the Python's standard binary search module.*

This is a good implementation of Binary Search; I just have a few nitpicks:

- How about a `high` and `low` overload?

  Instead of declaring your lower and higher `index` like this:

  > ```
  > lower_index = 0
  > upper_index = len(array) - 1
  > ```

  You could give them as argument overloads

  ```
  def binary_search_iterative(array, item, low=0, high=None):
      if high is None:
          high = len(array)
      ...
  ```
- Change your comments accordingly

  *Don't mix comments and docstrings, stick with docstrings if you want to explain arguments*

  > ```
  > """iteratively return the index of the item with binary search or None if not found"""
  > # Sorted array that has to be the condition
  > # go through several iteration until we found this
  > # First, set the lower_index = 0
  > # upper_index as the length of array -1
  > lower_index = 0
  > ```

  That could be this:

  ```
  """Return the index of the item with binary search or None if not found

  Keyword arguments:
  array -- the list to search in
  item -- the item to search for
  high -- the highest index to search in between (default highest index of the array)
  low -- the lowest index to search in between (default 0)
  """
  ```

  This uses the [PEP257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) Docstring style, but you may use your own as long as it is clear.
- Remove redundant comment

  Commenting is good, but don't overdo it; your code is good enough to speak for itself. These comments feel redundant:

  > ```
  > # calculate the middle index by sum the lower_index and upper_index and divide by 2
  > # check if the item is found
  > # Did not find
  > ```